# How to make status "active" or "expired" in a column in datatables?

Tags: javascript, mysql, datatable, laravel-5, datatables

I am using laravel 5 and I have a datatables like in the picture below. In the status column, I want to make if the date is more than current date, then the status is "expired". And if the date is less than or equal with the current date, then the status is "active". Else status is "deactive". Do you know how to do it?

[image]

> This below is my datatables javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var oTable = $('#surat').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '{!! route("datasurat") !!}',
            data: function (d) {
                d.jenis_surat = $('input[name=jenis_surat]').val();
                d.nomor_surat = $('input[name=nomor_surat]').val();
                d.perihal = $('input[name=perihal]').val();
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'no', name: 'no'},
            {data: 'jenis_surat', name: 'jenis_surat'},
            {data: 'nomor_surat', name: 'nomor_surat'},
            {data: 'perihal', name: 'perihal'},
            {data: 'date_to', name: 'date_to'},
            {data: 'status', name: 'status',
            mRender:  function(data, type, full) {
              if (strtotime($request['date_to']) < strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) || strtotime($request['date_to']) = '0000-00-00') {
                return '<span class="label label-default">Active</span>';
              }
              else if(strtotime($request['date_to']) > strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))){
                return '<span class="label label-default">Expired</span>';
              }
              else {
                return '<span class="label label-default">Deactive</span>';
              }
            }
          },
            {data: 'action', name: 'action'}
        ]
    });

    $('#search_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        oTable.ajax.reload();
       e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [column rendering](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) in the datatables initialization. The example code from datatables documentation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
            // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell (defined by the
            // `data` option, which defaults to the column being worked with, in
            // this case `data: 0`.
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return data +' ('+ row[3]+')';
            },
            "targets": 0
        },
            { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 3 ] }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

This will generate the first column with the data provided in the first column combined with the data provided in the 3rd column. You could use it in a similar way to compare data from one column to another and then define a string to render.

Here's a rough idea of how you might use it with your data:

```
columns: [
        {data: 'no', name: 'no'},
        {data: 'jenis_surat', name: 'jenis_surat'},
        {data: 'nomor_surat', name: 'nomor_surat'},
        {data: 'perihal', name: 'perihal'},
        {data: 'date_to', name: 'date_to'},
        {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
        ]
columnDefs: [
        {
            "render": function(data, type, row) {
                if (strtotime(row.date_to) < strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) {
                    return '<span class="label label-default">Active</span>';
                }
                else if (strtotime(row.date_to) > strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) {
                    return '<span class="label label-default">Expired</span>';
                }
                else {
                    return '<span class="label label-default">Deactive</span>';
                }
             }, "targets": [5]
        }
        ]
```

Comment: I've tried it, and I've got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in columnsDefs.
The row.date_to, is it read the data in the row date? Do you know how if the date_to not in the datatables display? let's say it is in the database.

Comment: What does your input data look like? Even if the date_to column is hidden it shouldn't matter for using the column. row.date_to should be reading the data from the date_to column

Comment: Annd now I realize my code put row.date_to in both cases. My mistake - one of those should be the current date. I'll edit

Comment: My code also had a typo: It is "columnDefs", not "columnsDefs".

Comment: There are no `strtotime` and `date` functions in JavaScript. This is a PHP code that needs to be reimplemented in JavaScript.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Ah, I assumed they were functions hendraspt had made. Thanks